# How to Query a Model based on its Relation in Strapi

Tags: javascript, strapi

Hope you are all having a nice day!  :)
I have tried to google my question but never can get a working example.

I have a model for *Projects*.  *Projects* has a *1:n* relationship with the model *Members*.
If I use:

```
strapi.query('project').find({id: 1});
```

I get:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Project 1', members: [...]}
```

So basically I am able to find a *Project* by its *ID* and I get a list of its *Members*.

BUT how would I go about getting a list of all members that belong to Project with ID = 1?

```
strapi.query('member').find(...);
strapi.query('member').search(...);
```

The closest I got was using:

```
strapi.query('member').search({_q: 'Project Name'});
```

This is however not close enough.  It is more of a work around.  I would really like to be able to do this in a clean way by using the IDs of the *Project*.   Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?  Any examples are greatly appreciated!   Thank you!  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to do this is:

```
strapi.query('member').find({name:'','project.id':id});
```

Above is AND find

```
strapi.query('member').find({name:''},['project.id',id]);
```

Above is OR find

Comment: UP! +How to query it when the relation is A `has many` B?

Comment: I assume this is with Strapi v3?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a custom controller function in project/controller/project.js

```
getMembers: async ctx => {
  const {id} = ctx.params; 
  const project = await strapi.services.project.findOne({id});
  
  return project ? project.members : [];
}
```

Make sure that you expose the route. Add the following in project/config/routes.json

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/projects/get-members/:id",
  "handler": "project.getMembers",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
},
```

You can also change the "path" property to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: /projects/:id/get-members would align better with naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

In **Strapi v4**, using entityService:

```
strapi.entityService.findMany('api::member.member', {        
    filters: {
        project: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to add details of the project with each record:

```
strapi.entityService.findMany('api::member.member', {        
    filters: {
        project: {
            id: 1
        }
    },
    populate: {
        project: true
    }
});
```